# How do i support RouteParams on page reload using Angular 2 Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-routing, angular

I'm using the Router and RouteParams in Angular 2 Dart.

My routes are as follow:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', component: ViewLanding, as: 'home'),
  const Route(path: '/landing', component: ViewLanding, as: 'landing'),
  const Route(path: '/flights', component: ViewFlights, as: 'flights'),
  const Route(path: '/picker/:cityDepart/:cityArrival/:dateDepart/:dateArrival/', component: ViewFlights, as: 'picker'),
  const Route(path: '/order/:id/:level/:dateDepart/:dateArrival/', component: ViewOrder, as: 'order'),
  const Route(path: '/order/complete', component: ViewComplete, as: 'orderComplete')
])
```

// Application Entry Point:

```
void main() {
  print('-- Main.dart 2 --');
  bootstrap(Tickets, [
    routerInjectables,
    client_classes,
    // The base path of your application
    bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue('/'),
    // uncomment this if you want to use '#' in your url
    bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy)
  ]);
}
```

This works fine with router-outlet / router-link / router.navigate

However, on page reload - I don't get a positive match for routes with params. IE: if I refresh `http://localhost:8080/#/picker/SAN/SFO/2015-01-01/2015-04-02` - I go to a the parent view with no child routes. This symptom is true for any route with params.

Navigating directly to or refreshing to: `http://localhost:8080/#/flights/`  - works as expected - the ViewFlights component is instantiated

**Symptoms:** 
routing with params fails.

**Question:** 
How do I define route configurations to work with parameters on refresh

**Links:**
https://github.com/rightisleft/web_apps_dart/blob/angular2/web/main.dart
https://github.com/rightisleft/web_apps_dart/blob/angular2/lib/client/tickets.dart

Comment: Did you end up with a solution on this?

Comment: This was supposed to be fixed in alpha31 (see [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2920) and [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c177d88)), although that looks to be only for the URL, not the params. This should be issued in their git for reviewing.

Comment: I just tested this again with alpha 37

Comment: Same issue in the beta!

Comment: did you try
(inject router ans Location in the constructor of the first component) and use: 
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.location.path());

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to subscribe to the router events in your component to update the old params with new, and then update your UI.

I assume your problem is when you open an url `http://localhost:8080/#/picker/SAN/SFO/2015-01-01/2015-04-02`, and then navigates to `http://localhost:8080/#/picker/SAN/SFO`. What you do is changing the route, but the component is already instantiated, meaning the new param will not be updated (nor removed).
What I usually do is the following in your parent component

## Angular 5

```
constructor(private router:Router){
 // Subscribe to the router events. 
 // It may be a good idea to assign this subscription to a variable, and then do an unsubscribe in your ngOnDestroy().
 this.router.events.subscribe(event=>{ 
  if(event instanceof ActivationEnd){
   var cityDepart = event.snapshot.params["cityDepart"];
   var cityArrival = event.snapshot.params["cityArrival"];
   var dateDepart = event.snapshot.params["dateDepart"]; 
   var dateArrival = event.snapshot.params["dateArrival"];
   // do some logic
  }
 });
}
```